# Java script error at line:36,char:3,Error:object expected,code:0,URL:http:\\localhost:6741/content.html

Tags: javascript, http, http-headers, xmlhttprequest

I am working on a client server application,in which we open client on our pc by `URL:http:\\[ip of server]:[port no]`.
The client's GUI is divided into parts and right click is disabled on left pane.

One of our Customer is getting the error (title), so the right click works on the left pane also which generate the error. The error line is

```
html.append(" writeAppletObject('appdiv', '").append(
                getParameter("javaclsid")).append(
                "', '2048', '2048', 'ContentGeneratorApplet', 'ContentGeneratorApplet', inner);"
```

What could be the reason of this error? Customer is saying they opens it first time successfully but afterwards in every attempt they are getting this error...

Note: My application start by using the URL mentioned in IE, and one pop-up comes in which we perform every action of the apllication and original window we can close as they are only for starting.
My customer is using IE8 and OS is Xp.

I compared the iehttpheader for both the successful and unsuccessful attempt, I noticed in both the case Two times GET /content.html HTTP/1.1 and GET /startNSM.html HTTP/1.1(part of ui) request is made. In success attempt when second requst is made it is served, but in failure case GET /startNSM.html HTTP/1.1 is served in first request and we are getting the mentioned error in content.html.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.... Thanks in Advance

Comment: What does this have to do with Java?

Comment: Can we see the context?

Comment: @AndreiNemes context means? are you asking the code of content.html or something else?

Comment: @RajeshKumar you just showed a 2 line error message with some cryptic applet code. How is anyone supposed to understand something from that? Show some code, or link to the page itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i did not find any way to prevent such requests... i sent reply for it.... HTTP 404 Not Found...